# Python 3.5 / 3.6 code depending on dict insertion order

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.5, python-3.6, ordereddictionary

I wrote some code on Python 3.6 that I discovered was dependent on the dict insertion ordering of keys that is new in 3.6 and will be guaranteed in 3.7.
I would like to support 3.5. I have this in the beginning of my file:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[1] < 6:
    from collections import OrderedDict
else:
    OrderedDict = dict
```

Which seem to work. I assume dict might be faster than OrderedDict, although I did not check this. My question is, is this the way to do this or is there some more systematic/prettier/more pythonic or generally better way for any reason?

Comment: There's no specific difference between common functionalities but `OrderDict()` had many extra functionalities compare to a simple dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution works fine, but I would caution against replacing standard library name with anything else, this might confuse someone trying to use OrederedDict (and finding out it's just dict) down the line.

I propose this:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[1] < 6:
    from collections import OrderedDict as ordered_dict
else:
    ordered_dict = dict
```

Comment: I think that renaming to ordered_dict is the way to go.